# how to use google calendar api in .net MVC 2 using this sample https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

Tags: .net, api, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-2

We have a legacy application which is written in .Net MVC 2 and required to use google calendar API. I have found this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) which is mentioned prerequisites VS 2013 and above. Is there any way to use google calendar API in VS 2010.